# Shot noise coupled quantum system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, noise, nanoscience

I have a question about noise in a coupled quantum system. Suppose you have two parallel 1D waveguides, which are separated from each other by a thin tunneling barrier. The subband energies of the respective first levels are the same, and the wave functions of the two energy levels overlap. The system is at a temperature of $T$ = 4.2 K, and the electrons move due to thermal excitation. Due to the wave function overlap, the electrons can tunnel through the barrier. Does the tunneling of electrons through the barrier in this case result in shot noise even though no voltage is applied to the system?